# Ordered delivery BizTalk performance

Tags: biztalk, sequence, orchestration

Is there an alternative to the "ordered delivery" on a send port in BizTalk? The sequence of the message is very important to me, so I created an orchestration that suspends the message when it is not in sequence, and resumes it when it is in sequence. I use a long running orchestration and direct port binding.

Now some messages are processed faster in the send pipeline, so it happens that sometimes the messages aren't in sequence (I use file adapter...). 
Now when I check the "ordered delivery" the messages are in sequence no matter what, but the performance is really really bad (messages get bulked up in the send ports), so I need to find an alternative for the ordered delivery in the send port.

Any suggestions?

thx

Answer (score 1):

Now ordered delivery does obviously add a lot of overhead with the FIFO pattern.  Take a look at this [article](http://biztalkhotrod.com/Issues.aspx) and look a the FIFO article in the first issue.  Also take a look at BizTalk performance in general to help speed up some of the other areas on your solution.  Now I've seen a few people try their own custom solution to ordering via .net and SQL and performance wasn't that much better because the ordering pattern takes time to process.  ALso take a look at these resources around performance in general:

- Considersations when planning a perf test -
  http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972201.aspx
- BizTalk 2006 adapter performance numbers -
  http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972200.aspx
- If your transport in or out is SOAP, read this scalability study -
  http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972198.aspx
- Good proof points for BizTalk performance with relation to infrastructure
  setup - http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms864801.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple locations the data is being sent to?  So, it has to be in sequence but could be partioned out.  If so you can use correlation and ordered delivery and have several pipes that deliver and speed the process up.